# Time complexity of this python function

Tags: python, algorithm, sorting, big-o, time-complexity

Here's a function given by a friend:

```
def sort1(lst):
    swapFlag = True
    iteration = 0
    while swapFlag:
        swapFlag = False
        for i in range(len(lst)-1):
            if lst[i] > lst[i+1]:
                temp = lst[i+1]
                lst[i+1] = lst[i]
                lst[i] = temp
                swapFlag = True

        L = lst[:]  # the next 3 questions below refer to this line
        iteration += 1
    return lst
```

I think its time complexity is O(2^n); what does everyone else think?

Comment: *given by a friend*. Glad you and your professor are on such friendly terms!

Comment: Yes that is `O(n^2)`. ...wait, are you saying it's `O(2^n)`?

Comment: Downvoters: Please elaborate. The question is clear, and the OP showed an effort (he said what he thinks the complexity is). If you find a question 'silly' or 'easy' - it is NOT a reason to downvote.

Comment: @amit Because trying to obfuscate (very incompetently though, I mean what the hell is with that comment?) that this is clearly a homework question is generally frowned upon by many people.

Comment: @amit Also, it's not clear why they think the complexity is what it is, and what they want for an answer.  It might be that the question is "Why is the complexity `O(n^2)`?" and the OP was hoping that would be answered when someone agreed.

Answer (score 0):

The complexity is `O(n^2)`. This is basically an implementation of [**bubble sort**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort).